# How to correctly add floating numbers in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point

I am trying to add `0.2` value to constant `x where x = 8` in a loop that runs to 100. Following is the code

```
 x = 8
>>> for i in range(100):
...     x += 0.2
...
>>> x
```

but everytime I get different answer and calculation always incorrect. I read about [Floating Point Arithmetic Issue and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) but there should be some way around this. Can I use `doubles` (if they exists) ? I am using Python 2.7

**UPDATE:**

```
  import time
x=1386919679

while(1):

        x+=0.02
        print "xx %0.9f"%x
        b= round (x,2)
        print "bb %0.9f"%b

        time.sleep(1)
```

**output**

```
xx 1386933518.586801529
bb 1386933518.589999914
xx 1386933518.606801510
bb 1386933518.609999895
xx 1386933518.626801491
bb 1386933518.630000114
```

**Desired output**
I want correct output, I know If just write `print x` it will be accurate. But my application require that I should print results with 9 precision. I am newbie so please be kind.

Comment: Can you tell me what you expect `sum` to do? Also, I'm wondering if you really have a problem with floating point precision or with your code? Can you give a specific example of the result you expect and the various different, incorrect results you are getting?

Comment: This question and the code in it are unclear as to the intended result. What are you expecting? The code provided will "correctly" compute 8 + 0.2 * 100, is this not intended?

Comment: @kobejohn Sorry, I just copied it wrong here. I just wanted to see what has been added.

Comment: @AhmedDurrani If you want a good answer, please provide exactly what you expect and exactly what you are getting.

Comment: Does "print results with 9 precision" mean with nine significant digits, or with nine decimal places after the decimal point? Nine significant digits is achievable with good practices using double. Nine places after the decimal point with ten before it requires a total of 19 significant digits, which requires a different data type.

Comment: can you try the constant as 8.0 instead of 8

Answer (score 0):

You can use double-precision floating point, sure. You're already using it by default.

As for a way around it:
`x += 0.2 * 100`

I know that sounds facile, but the solution to floating point imprecision is not setting `FLOATING_POINT_IMPRECISION = False`. This is a fundamental limitation of the representation, and has no general solution, only specific ones (and patterns which apply to groups of specific situations).

There's also a rational number type which can exactly store `0.2`, but it's not worth considering for most real-world use cases.